# How can I make "two questions in one" in python?

Tags: python

So Im making like a quiz sort of adventure game in Python. And as you can see, at the very start I have a guess=input statement. And then I have all my if statements. And so I said for the first line of it when you press A, it will print that text out. And the text says to say another answer. However, it stops me from entering anything else after I type in A. how can i resolve this so I'm able to say more than 1 word?

```
print('\n')
if guess=input ("You drive to your house, and you notice that the doors are all unlocked and some chairs are flipped over. You also hear some footsteps and hammering in the guest room. What do you do? A: Go in the room and see what is going on, B: Yell you are calling the cops and hide C: Grab a knife and head in the room D: Get too scared and run away out the door ").strip()
if guess.upper() == "A":
    print("Maybe not the wisest choice... He is there with a loaded gun aimed at you. What do you do? E: Panic and just sob and close your eyes F: Attempt a ninja move and try to kick him G: Try to distract him and then push him from the behind so he falls on the ground H: Try to talk him out of aiming the gun at you")
if guess.upper() == "E":
    print("Not the best idea, he shot you and you died.")
    return
if guess.upper() == "F":
    print("It worked! he was thinking about if he really wanted to do this and got distracted. You grabbed him by the hands then tied him up behind his back on the ground and called the cops. He was arrested. ")
    print("Turns out he was most wanted! Now you have 2 options. I: Get $200,000 now from the goverment for capturing a most wanted man, or J: Get $700,000 in 2 years from the goverment for capturing a most wanted man. ")
if guess.upper() == "I":
    balance = balance + 200000
    print("If you don't need the money right now because you aren't struggling, than why did you do this? you could get more than 2x more by waiting!")
if guess.upper() == "J":
    print("Smart option! no gains now but you will get a way bigger gain in 2 years! as long as you weren't struggling financially this was a great option.")
if guess.upper() == "B":
    print("You made him madder and he did not want to get involved with the police, so he shot you, you died.")
    return
if guess.upper() == "C":
    print("You got lucky! he did not notice you, you stabbed him and he died. You called the cops and they gave you a reward because he was most wanted. They gave you two options for a reward. K: Audi R8 spider right now, or L: Batmobile in 10 years.")
if guess.upper() == "K":
    print("You got a Audi R8 right now! it is a very nice car, but you already have one and you would have the coolest one ever in 10 years!")
if guess.upper() == "L":
    print("Nice choice. You realized you already had a car so you would get a amazing one in 10 years.")
if guess.upper() == "D":
    print("This did not work. He saw you running and shot you from a ways away, you died.")
    return


print("Total Balance:$",balance)

keepgoing = False
```

Comment: `if guess=input` is not valid syntax.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I just removed the if from it, it still dosen't let me. It runs the code, but once i get to that part in the code it wont let me put text in twice, it just stops.

Comment: Yeah, how do you expect to? You don't ask for input more than once.

Comment: what would I have to do to my code so I can enter input for more than once in that stanza of code? @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Comment: Woah, you'd need to do a lot. For starters, you need to structure your choices. You'll need to take in input in multiple places. I leave that to you.

Comment: Can you please copy and paste my code edited correctly? I've been trying for hours to do what you just said and I haven't found luck but i probably was not doing it correctly and at this point I just want this part of my whole code to work. It shouldn't take too long. @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Comment: Uhm, I'm not sure that's a good idea. I don't know how you want your code structured...

Comment: as long as it functions I don't care how it's structured, please? @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Comment: https://pastebin.com/rYfrKGvu

Answer (score 1):

[This was answered by @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45094274/how-can-i-make-two-questions-in-one-in-python#comment77161351_45094274):

```
def start():
    guess = input("You drive to your house, and you notice that the doors are all unlocked and some chairs are flipped over. You also hear some footsteps and hammering in the guest room. What do you do? A: Go in the room and see what is going on, B: Yell you are calling the cops and hide C: Grab a knife and head in the room D: Get too scared and run away out the door ").strip()

    if guess.upper() == "A":
        guess = input("Maybe not the wisest choice... He is there with a loaded gun aimed at you. What do you do? E: Panic and just sob and close your eyes F: Attempt a ninja move and try to kick him G: Try to distract him and then push him from the behind so he falls on the ground H: Try to talk him out of aiming the gun at you")

        if guess.upper() == "E":
            print("Not the best idea, he shot you and you died.")
            return

        elif guess.upper() == "F":
            guess = input("It worked! he was thinking about if he really wanted to do this and got distracted. You grabbed him by the hands then tied him up behind his back on the ground and called the cops. He was arrested.\nTurns out he was most wanted! Now you have 2 options. I: Get $200,000 now from the goverment for capturing a most wanted man, or J: Get $700,000 in 2 years from the goverment for capturing a most wanted man. ")

            if guess.upper() == "I":
                balance = balance + 200000
                print("If you don't need the money right now because you aren't struggling, than why did you do this? you could get more than 2x more by waiting!")

            elif guess.upper() == "J":
                print("Smart option! no gains now but you will get a way bigger gain in 2 years! as long as you weren't struggling financially this was a great option.")

    elif guess.upper() == "B":
        print("You made him madder and he did not want to get involved with the police, so he shot you, you died.")
        return

    elif guess.upper() == "C":
        guess = input("You got lucky! he did not notice you, you stabbed him and he died. You called the cops and they gave you a reward because he was most wanted. They gave you two options for a reward. K: Audi R8 spider right now, or L: Batmobile in 10 years.")

        if guess.upper() == "K":
            print("You got a Audi R8 right now! it is a very nice car, but you already have one and you would have the coolest one ever in 10 years!")

        elif guess.upper() == "L":
            print("Nice choice. You realized you already had a car so you would get a amazing one in 10 years.")

    elif guess.upper() == "D":
        print("This did not work. He saw you running and shot you from a ways away, you died.")
        return

start()
```

I removed def main from it at the start because I already had def main and then it worked. Appreciate it and thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer.

```
balance = 0
print('\n')
guess=input ("You drive to your house, and you notice that the doors are all unlocked and some chairs are flipped over. You also hear some footsteps and hammering in the guest room. What do you do? A: Go in the room and see what is going on, B: Yell you are calling the cops and hide C: Grab a knife and head in the room D: Get too scared and run away out the door ").strip()
if guess.upper() == "A":
    guess1 = input("Maybe not the wisest choice... He is there with a loaded gun aimed at you. What do you do? E: Panic and just sob and close your eyes F: Attempt a ninja move and try to kick him G: Try to distract him and then push him from the behind so he falls on the ground H: Try to talk him out of aiming the gun at you")
    if guess1.upper() == "E":
        print("Not the best idea, he shot you and you died.")
    elif guess1.upper() == "F":
        print("It worked! he was thinking about if he really wanted to do this and got distracted. You grabbed him by the hands then tied him up behind his back on the ground and called the cops. He was arrested. ")
        guess2 = input("Turns out he was most wanted! Now you have 2 options. I: Get $200,000 now from the goverment for capturing a most wanted man, or J: Get $700,000 in 2 years from the goverment for capturing a most wanted man. ")
        if guess2.upper() == "I":
            balance = balance + 200000
            print("If you don't need the money right now because you aren't struggling, than why did you do this? you could get more than 2x more by waiting!")
        elif guess2.upper() == "J":
            print("Smart option! no gains now but you will get a way bigger gain in 2 years! as long as you weren't struggling financially this was a great option.")
elif guess.upper() == "B":
    print("You made him madder and he did not want to get involved with the police, so he shot you, you died.")
elif guess.upper() == "C":
    guess3 = input("You got lucky! he did not notice you, you stabbed him and he died. You called the cops and they gave you a reward because he was most wanted. They gave you two options for a reward. K: Audi R8 spider right now, or L: Batmobile in 10 years.")
    if guess3.upper() == "K":
        print("You got a Audi R8 right now! it is a very nice car, but you already have one and you would have the coolest one ever in 10 years!")
    elif guess3.upper() == "L":
        print("Nice choice. You realized you already had a car so you would get a amazing one in 10 years.")
elif guess.upper() == "D":
    print("This did not work. He saw you running and shot you from a ways away, you died.")

print("Total Balance:$", balance)

keepgoing = False
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a while loop which is always true and then try to make a condition which your code escapes the while loop. Your code checks if an statement is true, in your case guess.upper()=A and then runs the code within the if statement and skips the rest of the code. Let's say you ask the user whenever you enter Z, the program ends. You can rewrite your code as:

```
While true:
  {your code}
  If guess.upper=='Z':
     Break
```

Your second line is also wrong. What exactly do you want to do over there?